# Selenium Web Scraping: Loop problems and stale element not found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape this website: https://www.cbf.com.br/futebol-brasileiro/atletas/campeonato-brasileiro-serie-a/2023

But I am facing several problems like loops that do not work and a "state element not found" bug.

I will explain.

First, my code:

```
# Importar bibliotecas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Instalar Webdriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Abrir aba Web
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
# Localizar website e entrar
website = 'https://www.cbf.com.br/futebol-brasileiro/atletas/campeonato-brasileiro-serie-a/2023'
driver.get(website)
# Maximizar aba Web
driver.maximize_window()
# Inplicit wait de 5 segundos para renderizar a página ao abrir
time.sleep(5)

# Criar listas vazias para armazenar a informação que queremos
jogador = []

#Not in use now.
comp = []

anos = []
competições = []

# Tests
an = ['2013']
co = ['Campeonato Brasileiro de Futebol Série B']

close_cookies = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//button[@id="cookie-banner-lgpd-action"]')
close_cookies.click()

# Encontrar todos os anos no seletor de anos da página e anexá-los na lista anos
years = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//select[@id="years"]'))

for year in years.options:
    anos.append(year.text)

# Encontrar todas as competições no seletor de competições da página e anexá-las na lista competições
competitions = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//select[@id="competitions"]'))

for competition in competitions.options:
    competições.append(competition.text)

for ano in anos:
    years.select_by_visible_text(ano)

    for competição in competições:
        competitions.select_by_visible_text(competição)

        while True:
            try:
                # Explicit Wait para esperar os elementos desejados aparecerem na página
                container = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="table m-t-30"]')))
                products = WebDriverWait(container, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/tr[position() > 1]')))

                # Encontrar os elementos que desejamos extrair por xpath e anexar todos em suas devidas listas (criadas acima)
                for product in products:
                    jogador.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//a").text)
            except:
                pass

            # Try e Except para pular erros quando a página se encontra vazia (sem a presença de elementos para extrair)
            try:
                # Encontre o botão "Next" (substitua pelo seu seletor XPath correto)
                next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@rel="next"]')
                next_button.click()
            except:
                pass
```

When I run this part of the code:

```
for ano in anos:
    years.select_by_visible_text(ano)

    for competição in competições:
        competitions.select_by_visible_text(competição)

        while True:
            try:
                # Explicit Wait para esperar os elementos desejados aparecerem na página
                container = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="table m-t-30"]')))
                products = WebDriverWait(container, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/tr[position() > 1]')))

                # Encontrar os elementos que desejamos extrair por xpath e anexar todos em suas devidas listas (criadas acima)
                for product in products:
                    jogador.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//a").text)
            except:
                pass

            # Try e Except para pular erros quando a página se encontra vazia (sem a presença de elementos para extrair)
            try:
                # Encontre o botão "Next" (substitua pelo seu seletor XPath correto)
                next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@rel="next"]')
                next_button.click()
            except:
                pass
```

It scrapes the first championship, but the loops for years(anos) and championships(competições) do not work and the code crashes.

Second, when I try to use the "Tests" lists inside the "anos" and "competições" loops, I get the "stale element not found." error.

I saw some StackOverflow articles about this error and [this](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/#:%7E:text=Stale%20Element%20means%20an%20old,then%20the%20StaleElementReferenceException%20is%20thrown.) link. But I am new into programming and could not understand how to apply the solutions.

May someone help me, please?

Comment: years = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//select[@id="years"]'))
 You could always refind this element prior to selecting it in the loop. What occurs is you navigate from this page and the element becomes stale.

Comment: It did not worked. I tried changing the xpath and tried this:
`years_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'years')))
competitions_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'competitions')))
years_select = Select(years_element)
competitions_select = Select(competitions_element)

for ano in anos:
    years_select.select_by_visible_text(ano)
    time.sleep(3)

    for competição in competições:
        competitions_select.select_by_visible_text(competição)
`